# UV texture grid sizes for Mobile characters

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, materials, texture-baking

Is 512x512 a too small for a character in unity? what size texture would be good for a main character in unity? i know that the texture can go up to really high like 8000 but what a reasonable decently detailed that wont make the game sluggish or take up to many resources. 1024? 2048? whats the goldilocks number? thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need to, but as separate posts. I suggest taking the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and familiarising yourself with the site by visiting the [help centre](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I didnt know that. I thhought it would be like reddit and I needed a certain amount of points. So instead I tried to compress my questions into 1 page. Can people still answer the questions as they are pretty much related to one thing I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: They may be related, and you can reference your previous questions when asking new ones, but they should still be separate.

Comment: Yessir! :) i will do that

Comment: Perhaps something in the node editor could help you? Try looking on yt for a nodes tutorial. I haven't done nodes much, so sorry if I am a little vague.
I liked to lie idea of separating each body bart, perhaps that will work!

Comment: What would you suggest looking for? I have tons of tabs open for multiple things but none seem to hit the sweet spot of info. any help would be great. thanks

Comment: changed it! sorry for the multiple post lol

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about blender, but other software.

Comment: It is about blender. the thing is, I am doing the texturing in blender. all the work in blender. its only going into Unity afterwards and i want it to work. So pretty much, Is 512x512 a good size to texture a character mesh or should I go higher? This is for a mobile platform.